# nginx cant access to backend server in vps but we can access to backend by browser directly

Tags: nginx

The configuration of nginx is as follows

```
 events {
     worker_connections  4096; 
 }
 http {

 upstream myproject {
    server ip_adder:80;
    server ip_adder:8080;
  } 

 server { 
   listen          80;
   location / { 

       proxy_pass      http://myproject;

   }
  } 
}
```

I run servers in vps,
when i request to ip_adder:80 by browser directly i see response.
but i request to nginx to redirect upstream i see 502 badGateway response.

anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1):

This problem is solved by this method;
Your upstream server ports are probably filtered or closed. Please refer to this link for further review
https://nmap.org/book/man-port-scanning-basics.html

Comment: yes.this worked for me.my upstream port is filtered.
thanks for your guidance